# Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header response in Laravel 5.3 Passport

Tags: cors, laravel-5.3

I'm new to Laravel and am doing some Laravel 5.3 Passport project with OAuth2.0 password grant. When I curl the API with the params it responds with token. However, in browser it needs an additional security that the endpoint should add because my request is coming from localhost while the API is located in my VM. Here's the error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

I know what the issue is but I don't know where to put to include that header since this is a third party app.

Thank you in advance experts. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2 CORS, GET not working with preflight OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748981/laravel-5-2-cors-get-not-working-with-preflight-options)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

The simple answer is to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `localhost` or `*`. Here's how I usually do it:

Create a simple middleware called `Cors`:

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

Add the following code to `app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php`:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

You can replace the `*` with `localhost` or keep it as it is.

Next step is to load the middleware. Add the following line to the `$routeMiddleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

```php
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

And the final step is to use the middleware on the routes to which you want to set the access origin headers. Assuming you are talking about the new api routes in laravel 5.3, the place to do it is `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`, inside the `mapApiRoutes()` function (you can remove or comment the previous code of the function):

```php
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['api', 'cors'],
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
         //Add you routes here, for example:
         Route::apiResource('/posts','PostController');
    });
```

Comment: I'm trying to make this work too ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991025/access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel-5-4-not-working-for-post)) but for some reason only the GET requests work. Any idea why POST is not working with my setup? Also.. the order of the middleware seems to matter.

Comment: I am making ajax call and this solution does not work for me, any suggestion?

Comment: Very clear for my Laravel 5.6 and Angular 5 Application.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of the last step just add this at the end of your routes: Route::get('/url','controller@function') -> middleware('cors');

Comment: Laravel 8 already has cors middleware included. But not working for me either (dont need auth since no users are stored in db)

Comment: Trying to implement this for my Laravel 9.x, agenda is to shoot API from front end but still CORS issue exist! Any recommendation?

Comment: I dont know what version you are using, but currently I am on 10, but 10 already have config for cors. is this for display? damn. and it is not working if I have to create middleware for CORS

Answer (score 74):

The simple answer is to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to localhost or *. Here's how I usually do it:

Add the following code to bootstrap/app.php:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

**WARNING**: Only do this in your developer environment.

Comment: i think it would be something more like this: 
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With,Authorization,  Content-Type, Accept');`

Comment: Would this leave your application open to attacks as you are also allowing everyone to Post to your entire application?

Comment: Never do this , it means any one can Post data to your application.

Comment: for development purpose only, it works
thank you

Comment: Finally something that works for Laravel 8..

Comment: Didn't work for me on L8.

Comment: I can't understand why sophisticated laravel package can't work but this simple solution is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 25):

You could also use the great [laravel-cors package by barryvdh](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors).

After you have the package installed, the easiest way to get CORS support for all your routes is to add the middleware like this in Http/Kernel.php:

```php
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

If you dont want to have CORS support on all your routes you should make a new OPTIONS route for `/oauth/token` and add the cors middleware to that route only.

**Edit for Laravel 8**

Laravel 8 already has CORS Support built in - `HandleCors` middleware is defined in your global [middleware stack by default](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#cors) and can be configured in your application's `config/cors.php` config file.

If you update your Laravel application be sure to change out barryvdh's package with the supplied middleware: `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class`

Comment: For now, it should `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class`, instead of `\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class`. [Docs](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#global-usage)

Comment: What should be the configuration in `config/cors.php` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` ?
Nobody is telling that.

Answer (score 9):

For those who didn't solve the problem setting route middleware in `App\Http\Kernel`, try to set global middleware. In `App\Http\Middleware\Cors`:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
}
```

In `App\Http\Kernel`:

```php
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

Comment: This worked!!! Earlier had Cors middleware in as route middleware which didn't help in resolving OPTIONS method requests(Preflight).
Setting Cors as global middleware handled all incoming requests including Preflight ones.
Adding to the answer, if allow-credentials is true, setting allow-origin to * won't work. Origin will have to be specific in case of Allow-Credentials as true. 
The origin can be fetched from the request headers and then be added to response header.

Comment: This method worked for me. If it's not working, you can try in incognito page.

Answer (score 7):

Create A Cors.php File in App/Http/Middleware and paste this in it.

```php
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    
use Closure;
    
    
class Cors 
{   
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        //ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            //The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
                return response()->json('OK',200,$headers);
            }
            $response = $next($request);
            foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
                $response->header($key, $value);
            }
            return $response;
        }
}
```

And Add This Line In Your Kernel.php after the "Trust Proxies::Class" Line.

```php
\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

Thats It You have Allowed All Cors Header.

Answer (score 5):

Just add this to your code Controller

```php
return response()->json(compact('token'))->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  "*");
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in content instead of simply pasting code, thanks!

Comment: can you explain why?

Answer (score 5):

After
`https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors`
I had to change in cors.php file as below

```php
/*
 * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
 */
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Comment: After setting above key value 'supports_credentials' => true in config/cors.php file in laravel, Clear your config cache (php artisan config:clear), route cache (php artisan route:clear) and normal cache (php artisan cache:clear). 

It will work fine for the defined path in the cors.php file.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful, you can not modify the preflight.
In addition, the browser (at least chrome) removes the "authorization" header ... this results in some problems that may arise according to the route design. For example, a preflight will never enter the passport route sheet since it does not have the header with the token.

In case you are designing a file with an implementation of the options method, you must define in the route file web.php one (or more than one) "trap" route so that the preflght (without header authorization) can resolve the request and Obtain the corresponding CORS headers.
Because they can not return in a middleware 200 by default, they must add the headers on the original request.

Answer (score 2):

If you've applied the CORS middleware and it's still not working, try this.

If the route for your API is:

```php
Route::post("foo", "MyController"})->middleware("cors");
```

Then you need to change it to allow for the OPTIONS method:

```php
Route::match(['post', 'options'], "foo", "MyController")->middleware("cors");
```

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason it's still not working.
First option for Laravel
The second option for any application

**FIRST OPTION:**

1. As in the example above, we create middleware

```bash
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

2. Add the following code to `app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php`:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next) 
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range'); 
}
```

Look closely, the amount of data in the header `->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',`

3. Step three, add middleware to `$routeMiddleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

**SECOND OPTION:**

1. Open the nginx.conf settings for your domain.

```bash
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-domain.conf
```

2. Inside the server settings server `{ listen 80; .... }` please add the following code:

```bash
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
```

Comment: First option was my solution to get assets back enabling cors

Answer (score 1):

Laravel since version ^7.0 comes out of the box with CORS enabled by default.

So you can modify Laravel's configuration instead of adding headers in custom middlewares yourself:

```
config/cors.php
```

```php
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'], //This line means allow origin

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false, 

];
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question but I was running into this issue with Laravel 8.  The cause of the problem was calling my api with an extra slash at the end of the url.

`fetch('https://myapi.com/api/endpoint/', ...`

Needed to be

`fetch('https://myapi.com/api/endpoint', ...`

Silly mistake but caused me some grief so I figured I'd share my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Few steps to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `localhost or *.`

Step 1: Create Cors middleware :

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

Step 2: Set header in Cors middleware like this

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
     
    return $response;
}
```

Step 3: We need to add Cors class in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```php
protected $middleware = [
    ....
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

Here no needed to check any middleware
because we add Cors class in `$middleware` in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution

Step 1: Create Cors middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

Step 2: Set header in Cors middleware inside handle function

```php
return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Step 3: Add Cors class in **app/Http/Kernel.php**

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

Step 4: Replace mapApiRoutes in **app/providers/routeServiceProvider.php**

```php
Route::prefix('api')
    ->middleware(['api', 'cors'])
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

Step 5: Add your routes in **routes/api.php**

```php
Route::post('example', 'controllerName@functionName')->name('example');
```

Answer (score 0):

For users of newer versions of Laravel, there is a cors.php file in the config dir.

Add your URLs to a proxy array and restart the laravel artisan server:

```
<?PHP

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
| or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
| in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
|
| To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
|
*/

'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,

'proxies' => [
  //All your cors URLs here. Like the example below:
   'http://192.168.100.106:9000',
],
```

];

Answer (score -1):

I am using Laravel 8 and just installed the `fruitcake/laravel-cors` and  use it in `app/Http/Kernel.php` like blow:

```
protected $middleware = [
      ....
         \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
```

**note :** **add it to end of array like me**

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily by adding headers in bootstrap/app.php

```bash
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```