# Laravel : add Cors header for static files

Tags: apache, laravel, nginx, header, cors

I have a Laravel app, which was hosted on Apache, but now has been migrated on nginx. I'm a totally newbie with nginx.
On Apache I had this in my htaccess :

`<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>`

The new hosting provider does not allow custom nginx configuration.

Is it possible to add a Cors header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *) for static font files (extensions : svg|ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2) in the Laravel app PHP code ? I tried ([Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header response in Laravel 5.3 Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429462/adding-access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel-5-3-passport)) without success, my guess is that static files are not targeted by that piece of code. Do you confirm ?

Is there a way to achieve this within my app's PHP code ?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use this in you server block or `nginx.conf` to apply globally.

```
location ~* \.(svg|ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Make sure to restart nginx server for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for this. But like I said, my hosting provider does not allow custom nginx configuration (which seems very annoying to me). Is it possible to do that within Laravel ?