# Adding CORS middleware removes token-based authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware

I have followed [the accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429462/adding-access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel-5-3-passport) to allow everyone to request my API providing that they give an auth token.

The code I have is exactly the same that in the answer.

The problem is that it removes the token-based authentication, everyone can send a request yes, but it works even without token. How should I do to have the header `access-control-allow-origin → *` and also a working authentication system?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add
`->header('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$request->header('Authorization'))` in the cors middleware.

Comment: I can still access my API without authentication.

Comment: then Use [Laravel cors Package by barryvdh] (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)