# No response data from Laravel API using Axios

Tags: laravel, axios, postman

I am setting up authentication using Laravel (Laravel Framework version 5.8.4) as a REST API, but when I make a post request using Axios, I get back an empty string.

Here is my code in Laravel:  "login" endpoint in my main controller:

```
 class MainController extends Controller
{

public function login(Request $request){

$data = [
'message' => 'yo'
];

return Response::json($data, 200);

 }
}
```

Here is my Axios code (from Vue.js method):

```
methods: {

      submitRegistration: function() {

    axios.post('http://envelope-api.test/api/auth/login', {
    name: this.form.name,
    email: this.form.email,
    password: this.form.password,
    password_confirmation: this.form.password_confirmation
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      console.log("here's the response")
      console.log(response);
    })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

    },
  }
```

Here is the response from Postman (it works!)

```
{
    "message": "yo"
}
```

Here is the response from my axios request in console (empty string, where's the data?) :

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

Comment: post your axios call code

Comment: and your route in php

Comment: post it in your question, press edit

Comment: ok, just updated code @AshleyBrown

Comment: If you open the whole console.log in the inspector, can you see the message? Try yo do `console.log(response.message)`

Comment: I just updated my question that the response from axios was in console @JacoboTapia

Answer (score 0):

To get data from `axios` you should use `response.data`, not just `response`.

Edit: Try to respond with the helper.

`response()->json($data);`

Comment: His `data` seems empty though :/

Answer (score 0):

I've got this figured out. Thanks for your help.

I had [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) chrome extension installed to allow CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) so I could do API requests from localhost (apparently, not needed for Postman?).

I turned it off and installed it locally on Laravel using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429462/adding-access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel-5-3-passport) post (answer from naabster)

After I installed this way, it worked regularly.