# Problem CORS policy with a new model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a new model "CategoryStatus" in my application.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategoryStatus extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'category_status';

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = ['status', 'category_id', 'user_id'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }
}
```

I try to access my model like this:

```
CategoryStatus::where('id', $id)->first()
```

But every time I receive an error with the CORS policy (when I make an axios call with views). I installed the `spatie' extension which works from the beginning.

> `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myapp.test/api/bilan' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   14:00:22.815`

When I do my query with `DB::` it works

I'm pretty sure it's not a CORS problem. Can you tell me why ?

Thank you

Comment: Add to VerifyCsrfToken.php Middleware perhaps?

Comment: You are using test in your domain

Comment: @Jeremy what is APP_URL set to in your .env file?

Comment: @MaksimIvanov http://myapp.test

Comment: @Jeremy try changing it to `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: @MaksimIvanov already tested, doesn't work :(

Comment: @Jeremy then your best guess is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429462/adding-access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel-5-3-passport or this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Note that in the blocked access notice it says that axios is in the'http://localhost'  domain, but Laravel responds from 'http://myapp.test'. So, the axios call should be in the same domain as Laravel or do you want to allow access from other origins?

Answer (score 2):

When you using soft delete option you need to add `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;`at the top of the model file and then add the `deleted_at` column to the `$fillable` array.

It's a little strange, but I don't know why this is happening.Even the Laravel document didn't mention it.