# Vue + Laravel + tinymce upload image blocked by CORS policy

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, tinymce-4

I want to upload images insinde the TinyMCE editor but i has been blocked by CORS policy. 
I had setting the CORS on my Laravel project. Other function is OK to get the data from this Laravel project

These are my Javascript settings:

```
uploadImg(blobInfo, success, failure) {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
      this.axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "/test2",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        withCredentials: false,
        data: formData
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
    }
```

These are my CORS settings:

```
public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $this->headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 1728000 
        ];

        $this->allow_origin = [
            'http://localhost',
            'http://localhost:8080',
            'http://localhost:8000',
        ];


        $origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : '';

        if (!in_array($origin, $this->allow_origin) && !empty($origin)){
            return new Response('Forbidden', 403);
        }


        if ($request->isMethod('options'))
            return $this->setCorsHeaders(new Response('OK', 200), $origin);

        $response = $next($request);
        $methodVariable = array($response, 'header');

        if (is_callable($methodVariable, false, $callable_name)) {
            return $this->setCorsHeaders($response, $origin);
        }
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * @param $response
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function setCorsHeaders($response, $origin)
    {
        foreach ($this->headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
        if (in_array($origin, $this->allow_origin)) {
            $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
        } else {
            $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '');
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

this is the error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNiLK.png)

Can anyone tell me where did i make a mistake? Thanks

Comment: You need to add the domain in CORS headers. In laravel you can check https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't really block by CORS, it could be some program error

Comment: Like Oyster said. If the server side script fails before the response, it can not return the cors headers. It would be helpful to see what response you get.

Comment: Could you show what headers are sent by browser for this preflight request?

Answer (score -1):

You could start Chrome or chromium with cors policy disabled.
This would be helpful for debugging
check this answer on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)
 check ths answer on how to do it in laravel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429462/adding-access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel-5-3-passport)

Comment: It should add the domain as an allowed one on CORS headers. This will be and issue even on production and this solution is just a temporary one.

Comment: edited answer.Like i said before its helpful in debugging, didn't say it was the best solution besides he has not moved the app to production.

Comment: in that case you should comment :) 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment

Comment: Thanks everyone I found the problem :)  Is my problem with returning data.