Laravel, Nuxt config for headers (cors)
error:
http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

nuxt axios config
import axios from "axios"

export default defineNuxtPlugin((NuxtApp) => {

    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000'

    return {
        provide: {
            axios: axios
        },
    }
})

*Laravel Cors*

    'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        '/login',
        '/register',
        '/logout',
        '/sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ],


    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];

the translator such settings do not work gives the above error
I tried the proxy and nothing worked (same error)
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = async function (req, res) {
    const { data, headers } = await axios({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
        url: req.url,
        method: req.method,
        headers: {
            ...req.headers,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        },
        data: req.body || null,
    });

    Object.keys(headers).forEach((key) => {
        res.setHeader(key, headers[key]);
    });

    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
};

nuxt.config.ts
serverMiddleware: [
    {
      path: '/api',
      handler: '~/server-middleware/api-proxy.js',
    },
  ],


Adding a CORS header should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429462

solution
Install the CORS package for Laravel:
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors

or
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors

Add Cors middleware to the global middleware stack in the app/Http/Kernel.php file:
protected $middleware = [
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    or
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];

Post your Cors config file:
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"
After that, in the config/cors.php file, configure the allowed sources for your application:
'paths' => ['api/*'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,

this is all

This package has been deprecated since Laravel 9.2, and is now included in the Laravel core: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/blob/master/readme.md
