# Laravel 5.7 API with CORS issue

Tags: laravel, api, cors

I've already looked at [Laravel 5.2 CORS, GET not working with preflight OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748981/laravel-5-2-cors-get-not-working-with-preflight-options) which was helpful to diagnose the issue, but I'm still having issues.

The exact error:

```
Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

It's no longer failing as a result of the access control response, but it's still failing. How would I go about updating this?

Comment: Usually this will happen if the route is defined improperly...  Have you defined your route for the particular verb you're trying to access?

Comment: Thanks for your help - the error changed. Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr) and see if that answers your question.

Comment: After solving the previous error thanks to your help I was able to get it working... thanks!

Comment: I'm going to post my first comment as the solution, if you wouldn't mind, please mark it as resolved.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this will happen if the route is defined improperly... Check to make sure the route and its verb are properly defined.

Comment: Well, this has nothing to do with improper defining of routes. Proper headers need to be sent back to the client browser via a middleware.

Comment: That's correct, @vivek_23, and the middlewares take care of that part for you if the routes are properly defined.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this several times where it gives a CORS error yet if I check, the Access-Control-Allow-Headers it is actually present in the preflight response.
I noted that Laravel can sometimes return that CORS because of an issue with the controller/model that is involved with that request. I have experienced this 3 times and these were the 3 reasons:

- Using a trait in a model when I had not imported the actually trait into the model
- Had a typo in the model class definition e.g. `class Document implements Filee` instead of `File`
- I checked the laravel.log and it had an error that I was not implementing some abstract methods in the a certain model class (this was today, toiled for many hours!!!)

I write this, with examples, in the hope that it can actually help somebody. The issue is difficult to troubleshot given that it just gives a CORS error without much info about what the issue is at the back.

Good luck.