# could not connect laravel web socket from angular

Tags: angular, laravel

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MgBuvgw' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Did you search on this error? this question is already asked overhere https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/8559155

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748981/laravel-5-2-cors-get-not-working-with-preflight-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a security reasons browsers won't allow you to access other websites content until you specify with cors headers.

For more information on cors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Fix:

quick solution: in public/index.php add the following headers

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
```

For better control and good practice use this package:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Hi, We used the command you shared but actually we faced the above issue only while connecting with web socket. Other than that we can be able to fetch the data.