# Cross-Origin Request error when accessing static files

Tags: laravel, cors

I want to read a pdf file though the api, but it gives me this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

this is my cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => false,

    'max_age' => false,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

Will Cors help me in this scenario, or does the storage link folder need some other configrations in order for it to work?
How can I solve this error?

Comment: Hope this can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748981/laravel-5-2-cors-get-not-working-with-preflight-options

Comment: no, it didn't. Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

```php
Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing
```

This says most of it. You did not pass the **header** from the server. If you have access to the API (if you can modify it's code), then send this header from the API before sending any output request.

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *')
// change this for other methods that you allow to be exposed
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET, POST')
```

Comment: it didn't work, I tried adding it in the api function before returning the its data. but it didn't work. is that where I should put it

Comment: You can try adding it when you receive a request, so when you send the results anytime, this header will already be present in the result.